# How to serialize objects to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

How can i serialize two objects, of Class A and Class B, to xml so that it can be of the following format:

```
<root>
<objClassA> //Parent Node
  <objClassB> // child node of objClassA
  </objClassB>
</objClassA>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Serializable(true)]
public class objClassB
{
}

[Serializable(true)]
public class objClassA
{
    public objClassB instance;
}
```

Then use the XmlSerializer for an instance of objClassA and it will automatically place the instance of the b inside itself as a child.

Comment: But, i dont need the class B instance inside Class A. I just need to frame the xml in the above format. Is there any other way?

Comment: You'll have to serialize it yourself (custom).

Comment: In that case you need to implement IXmlSerializable on your class and add the WriteXml and ReadXml methods. Inside there you can add whatever child elements you desire.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

void Write(root rootInstance)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("filepath.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, rootInstance);
    }
}

    public class root
    {
        public ClassA objClassA { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
        public ClassB objClassB { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassB { }
```